# More efficient delete triggers in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, triggers

My PostgreSQL 9.2 database has many AFTER DELETE row-level triggers defined, which are used to  delete child rows when a parent row is deleted. (There are also many FKs with ON DELETE CASCADE in cases  where the child row references the parent row.) This works, but it's very slow when many rows need to be deleted. Is there a way to use statement-level triggers for this or some other way to make deletes more efficient? I cannot figure out how to get the deleted rows in a statement-level trigger function - or any useful information about what just happened, really.

Comment: Why not use Cascade deletes?

Comment: @Elias It won't do any good, since they're actually just row-level triggers under the hood right now anyway...

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much at the moment.

You could accumulate information about the rows to delete by inserting them into a side-table in your `BEFORE ... FOR EACH ROW` trigger, then have an `AFTER` statement-level trigger do the deletes from child tables, but that won't play well with built-in foreign key enforcement.

There's been periodic discussion of accumulating "change relations" for statement level triggers. That's what you want, but nobody's come up with a viable patch to implement it yet.

Comment: That sounds like a possibility. Why do you say it won't work well with FK enforcement? I don't see what the problem would be.

Comment: @EM FK constraints are themselves implemented as triggers; they'll fire whether or not you've already removed the rows.